# Add a UIImageView to a UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiimageview

Ive been stuck on this for a while now so any help will be greatly appreciated.

I have basically made a class called shape which is a `UIView` and I want to add an `UIImageView` to that `UIView`.

Here is my .h file:

```
@interface Shape : UIView {

 int blockWidth;
 int blockHeight;
 NSString *colour;

 IBOutlet UIImageView *blockView;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *blockView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *colour;

-(void)setColour:(NSString *)colour;
-(void)createShape:(int)blocksX :(int)blocksY;


@end
```

And here is my .m file:

```
@implementation Shape

@synthesize blockView;
@synthesize colour;

- (void)setColour:(NSString *)colour{
 NSLog(@"Colour: %@", colour);
}

-(void)createShape:(int)blocksX :(int)blocksY{
 self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
 blockView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);

 self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
 blockView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
 [self addSubview:blockView];

}

- (void)dealloc {

 [blockView release];
 [colour release];
 [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Thanks a lot!

Hey Again sorry if this is confusing but Im trying to port this c sharp code into objective, the code above is my first attempt and is obviously no where need finished but you can hopefully see what I'm trying to acheive, sorry but Im completely new to Objective C and it is completely different to other languages I am use to :S

```
public class Shape : UIView
    {
        public UIImageView blockView;

        private int blockWidth = 40;
        private int blockHeight = 40;


        public Shape (int startX, int startY ,string colour, int blocksX, int blocksY)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Colour: "+colour+" Blocks: "+blocksX+" "+blocksY);

            this.Frame = new RectangleF(startX,startY,blockWidth*blocksX,blockHeight*blocksY);
            this.UserInteractionEnabled = true;


            for(int i = 0; i<blocksX; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j<blocksY; j++)
                {
                    blockView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile("Images/Blocks/"+colour+"block.jpg"));
                    blockView.Frame = new RectangleF(blockWidth*i,blockHeight*j,blockWidth,blockHeight);
                    Console.WriteLine("I: "+i+" J: "+j);
                    this.AddSubview(blockView);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: have you tried adding an actual image to it?

Comment: Can you use the code block button? It makes your code easier to read for everyone. Also where do you attempt to add the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(deleted old text)

Actually, what you're doing in your C# code isn't that different in Objective-C (this code is untested!):

In the header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ShapeView : UIView {

}

@end
```

Implementation file:

```
#import "ShapeView.h"

#define kBlockWidth 40
#define kBlockHeight 40

@implementation ShapeView

- (id)initWithStartX:(int)startX startY:(int)startY colour:(NSString*)colour blocksX:(int)blocksX blocksY:(int)blocksY
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(startX, startY, kBlockWidth * blocksX, kBlockHeight * blocksY);

    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) != nil)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < blocksX; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < blocksY; j++)
            {
                UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Images/Blocks/%@block.jpg", colour]];
                UIImageView* blockView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

                blockView.frame = CGRectMake(kBlockWidth * i,
                                             kBlockHeight * j,
                                             kBlockWidth,
                                             kBlockHeight);

                [self addSubview:blockView];
                [blockView release];
            }
        }
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

This implementation simply adds the UIImageViews as subviews. Note that the `blockView` is allocated and configured, then added as a subview of `self`. Calling `-addSubview:` retains the new subview and actually adds it to the view hierarchy. Therefore, `blockView` is released right away. When the whole `ShapeView` object is deallocated, UIView's `-dealloc` implementation takes care of removing and releasing the subviews.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Eventually I will want to fill the UIView with multiple UIImageViews, I started off writing it in monodevelop but now im stuck as I have been asked to port it to objective c. I can show you the old c sharp code if that helps. Im not planning on using Interface Builder so im guessing I can remove the IBOutlet?

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot the code actually looks very similar to my C# code so it is very easy for me to read :)
However I do get the following error  with the line below

"if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) != nil)" 
//no super class declared in @interface for 'ShapeView'

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I omitted the `#import` statements. Now they're in the code above. I also fixed a copy&paste error (`kBlockWidth` and `kBlockHeight` were misspelled). It compiles for me now.

Comment: Yeah it compiles with me too :) you are an absolute hero! thanks a lot!